# How do I get a tooltip for my ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I think this should be simple, but I can't find the option!

How do I get a `tool-tip/alt` for my ActionLink??

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("New", "List", "FormSummary", new {childId = Child.Id}, new {Class = "action add"})%>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's html title attribute:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("New", "List", "FormSummary", new {childId = Child.Id}, 
  new {Class = "action add", title="My Tooltip" })%>
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Not needing child and as a VB.NET user  I used it in this way: @Html.ActionLink("New", "List", "FormSummary", New With {.Class = "action add", .title = "My Tooltip"})

Comment: Oooops the above code must be corrected to: @Html.ActionLink("New", "List", "FormSummary", Nothing, New With {.Class = "action add", .title = "My Tooltip"}) otherwise you will get a 404 error