# Need to implement tooltip in Asp.net MVC3-Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tooltip

I need to implement jquery tooltip in Asp.net MVC3-Razor view. Can anybody give some tips & samples to carry out this operation

Thanks,
Selva

Answer (score 5):

If you just want simple text to be shown in your tooltip, i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222105/how-do-i-get-a-tooltip-for-my-actionlink) to be the best solution -

:)

If you want to apply for different controls, do something like this -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.FieldName, new {title="Your Tooltip text goes here"})
```

works for everything except EditorFor.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the tooltip plugins that:

- Reuse a single container (vs. wrapping target elements in a bunch of curfty markup)
- Allow for tip content to be declared on the target element itself (via "data-" attributes)
- Allow full styling via css classes (on / off states, etc controlled by adding css classes as opposed to injecting inline style rules)

There are literally *tons* of options out there... when I last checked, this one was my personal preference:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

But there are many more... including one native to jQuery UI coming soon!

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/05/jquery-ui-19m1-tooltip/

Comment: hi, Thanks for ur answer...i need to how to implement the same in Razor engine(Asp.net Mvc3), can u help in that